# How to test whether two lists are equal in python

Tags: python, list, if-statement, equality

The following script is returning false, when I think that it should be returning true. Any idea what is going on here? Thanks so much, guys!

```
test=['Pop']
test1='Pop'

if (test==('POP' or 'Pop' or 'pop' or ['POP'] or ['Pop'] or ['pop'])):    
    print "yes"
else:
    print "no"
```

Currently, the output is, 'no'.

Comment: You aren't comparing two *lists*, you are comparing a list to a string.

Comment: `if test == 'POP' or '...' or '...'` isn't doing what you think it is: possibly have a look in the fine documentation how boolean logic works

Comment: To ignore case of a string, you can convert both operands to lowercase. `'POP'.lower() == 'poP'.lower()`

Comment: Are you sure? `['Pop'] == ['Pop'] is True`

Comment: Your new code won't even run. It uses test1 without assigning something to it.

Comment: Ok, I can't even get my script to be mistaken anymore. Wth! I mean, I'll take it, but I don't know what used to be wrong. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Then I **strongly** suggest reading the Python tutorial - if you're struggling and don't understand what everyone's said - you're going to run into serious problems later on

Comment: @Atticus29, try setting `test = 'Pop'`, and you'll see that your current version still doesn't work.

Comment: Nevermind. I restored the original error. I'm not as incompetent as I seem. Promise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't understanding how python processes the statement. Python isn't natural language.

```
if (test==(['Pop'] or 'Pop')):
```

Because the `or` is inside the parens, it processes it first. So it looks at

```
['Pop'] or 'Pop'
```

Since ['Pop'] is considered True, python reduces the whole statement to:

```
if (test==['Pop']):
```

At this point, it tests whether `test` is equal to `['Pop']`

What you are actually wanting to do is:

```
(test == ['Pop']) or (test == 'Pop')
```

This is completely different than

```
 test == (['Pop'] or 'Pop')
```

Comment: Or more traditionally written as `test in (['Pop'], 'Pop')`

Comment: @JonClements, I don't know about traditionally, but yes that's better.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly my confusion. Thank you for being able to identify this despite the shifting code above.

Comment: @Atticus29: also note that unless you're using your own class which has it's own comparison methods, equality tests would evaluate to False between objects of different types no matter what their contents are.

Answer (score 2):

If you write it like this, the if statement will be true when you use `test` or `test1`:

```
test=['Pop']
test1='Pop'
if (test in ('POP', 'Pop', 'pop', ['POP'], ['Pop'], ['pop'])):
    print "yes"
else:
    print "no"
```

You're basically creating a big tuple with all the possibilities: three strings and three lists. If your variable is present in there, the if statement is true.

Comment: I believe `if any(test == i for i in ('POP', 'Pop', 'pop', ['POP'], ['Pop'], ['pop'])):` would also work.

Comment: @JAB, yes, but why would ever want to do it that way?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: this is the right way of doing it, but it would better to explain what's wrong with the OP's approach.

Comment: @WinstonEwert So you can utilize a generator expression just for the heck of it. As an aside, Simeon didn't need to use parentheses with the `if` statement in C/Java style; `if test in ('POP', 'Pop', 'pop', ['POP'], ['Pop'], ['pop']):` has the same result.

Answer (score 1):

`test == (a or b)` is different from `test == a or test == b`.

`(a or b)` returns `a` iff `bool(a)` is True and `b` otherwise. Therefore `test == ('POP' or whatever)` is equivalent to `test == 'POP'` because `bool('POP')` is True as for any other non-empty string in Python.

To test multiple values you could use: `value in [a, b]`.

Note: `['a'] != 'a'` – the later is a string while the former is a list that contains a string.

In your case you could `test[0].lower() == 'pop'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
test=['Pop']
test1='Pop'
if test1 == 'POP' or test1 == 'Pop' or test1 == 'pop' or test1 == ['POP'] or test1 == ['Pop'] or test1 == ['pop']:
    print "yes"

else:
    print "no"
```

Each one is a separate test.

Comment: This is the closest answer to your question. The other ones are saying something completely different.

Comment: This always results in `if test1 == 'POP'`

Comment: This is just completely wrong. It will always say "yes" regardless of what's in test1

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the user is just trying to do a case insensitive comparison:

```
if test1.lower() == 'pop':
    print 'yes'
else:
    print 'no'
```